# Excel, dynamic referencing dates

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference, excel-indirect

I'm struggling to implement a dynamic reference within excel when using dates. The formula I'm using works with other strings but dates seem to be an issue.

`=INDIRECT(C$2&"!$C2")`

The first instance of C2 is equal to 04-01-2021, the same as the sheet (name) I want to reference.

*The second instance of C2 pulls in a [Y]es or [N]o which works fin if the references / sheets are not dates.*

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanx for looking,
Sam

EDIT:
I've tried using another suggestion but I'm still getting no joy.

`=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(C2,"dd-mm-yyyy")&"'!"&C2)`

This pulls in the date:

`=TEXT(C2,"dd-mm-yyyy")`

04-01-2021

What am I doing wrong with the *indirect* function?

EDITv2: I was going to upload an example but obviously I'm too dense to be able to find any sort of upload button / link on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it.

I was using dates and forgot to wrap my dates in speech marks for them to reference correctly.

Master Sheet C2 contents:

`="04-01-2021"`

Sheet name:

`04-01-2021`

Thanx for your help @Carter Bayer

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understanding what you are seeking to do. Based on your description, I think you are trying to reference the same cell in every worksheet based on a worksheet name?

If so, you should be able to reference the sheet name by simply adding ' to your indirect formula.

[Example workbook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVHpa.png)

Breaking it down:
Formula = INDIRECT("'"&SHEET_REF&"'CELL_REF")

1. Where SHEET_REF = Reference sheet name ([Reference: Retrieve sheet name](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-sheet-name-only))

=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)

2. Where CELL_REF = Cell reference ([Dynamic worksheet reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-worksheet-reference))

=!C2

The combined formula would be: INDIRECT("'"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"'!C2")

Let me know if this works or if I misunderstood your question.
-Carter

Comment: Hi Carter, thanx for the reply. The sheet I'm wanting to use the formula in is a "master sheet" and pulls in data from other sheets that are named as dates. e.g. 04-01-2021. My master sheet cell (C2) contents the date 04-01-2021. I want cell C3, on the master sheet, to reference C2's date and pull in the content from the sheet with the same name. I'll add an excel file to my OP when I get a moment. (I work with ASD children so it probably wont be straight away). Thanx again for your reply.

Comment: @SamC please attach a copy of your workbook and I'm happy to revise my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm too stupid to find an upload button to show you my example.